# Xubuntu 13.10 laptop display pop up from sleep?

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, 13.10, display-manager

Upgraded to Xubuntu 13.10 recently and noticed that when I put my Dell D620 laptop to sleep/hibernate (closed lid) the laptop display & configure settings & layout pop up appears? This doesn't happen if I activate hibernate/suspend from the menu just when I close the lid........any ideas anyone??

Regards, David

Comment: Does this happen on a supported Ubuntu release? If so please report back.